# How can i register a type with its interfaces as singleton using simple injector?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have models like below:

```
public interface IUserLookupService {
    Guid[] GetDirectChilds(Guid userId);
    Guid[] GetAllChilds(Guid userId);
    Guid GetDepartment(Guid userId);
}

public interface ICanRefreshCache{
    void Refresh();
}

public class XHandler : IEventHandler<UserNameChanged> { ... }
public class YHandler : IEventHandler<TeamCreated> { ... }

public class CachedUserLookupService
    : IUserLookupService,
    ICanRefreshCache,
    IEventHandler<UserNameChanged>
{
    private Func<ISession> _sessionFactory;
    private IDictionary<Guid, UserInfo> _users = new Dictionary<Guid, UserInfo>();

    public CachedUserLookupService(Func<ISession> sessionFactory) {
        _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void Handle(UserNameChanged ev) {
        // change cache with new event parameters
    }

    public void Refresh() {
        var session = _sessionFactory();
        // get user from db then create userinfo...
    }

    public Guid[] GetDirectChilds(Guid userId) {
        // code
    }

    public Guid[] GetAllChilds(Guid userId) {
           // code
    }

    public Guid GetDepartment(Guid userId) {
        // code
    }

    public class UserInfo
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public Guid? ParentId {get;set;}
    }
}

public class CachedTeamService
    : ITeamService,
    ICanRefreshCache,
    IEventHandler<TeamCreated>{
    // similar with CachedUserLookupService
}
```

My registration:

```
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IEventHandler<>),
    (closedServiceType, implementations) =>
    {
        container.RegisterAll(closedServiceType, implementations);
    },
    applicationAssembly, typeof(Constants).Assembly);

var serviceRegistrations = 
    from type in applicationAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
    where type.Name.EndsWith("Service")
    where !type.IsAbstract
    where !type.IsInterface
    select new
    {
        Services = type.GetInterfaces(),
        Implementation = type
    };

var lifeStyles = new Dictionary<Type, Lifestyle>()
{
    {typeof(CachedUserLookupService),Lifestyle.Singleton},
    {typeof(CachedTeamService),Lifestyle.Singleton}
};

List<Type> cacheableComponents = new List<Type>();
foreach (var reg in serviceRegistrations)
{
    foreach (var service in reg.Services)
    {
        Lifestyle lifeStyle;
        if (lifeStyles.TryGetValue(reg.Implementation, out lifeStyle) == false)
        {
            lifeStyle = Lifestyle.Singleton;
        }

        if (typeof(ICanRefreshCache) == service)
        {
            cacheableComponents.Add(reg.Implementation);
            continue;
        }

        container.Register(service, reg.Implementation, lifeStyle);
    }
}

container.RegisterAll(typeof(ICanRefreshCache), cacheableComponents);
```

I want to refresh all cache at system startup using ICanRefreshCache->Refresh method so I call:

Step 1:

```
container.GetAllInstances<ICanRefreshCache>().Each(c=>c.Refresh());
```

Step 2:

after I called `IEventHandler<UserNameChanged>` or any other interfaces type its belonging to  CachedUserLookupService (or CachedTeamService) any time, returning instance is different from Step 1 instance therefore this registration does not help me.

I need Simple Injector registration to supply below calls.

```
// must return Singleton CachedUserLookupService + other 
// IEventHandler<UserNameChanged> implementations
container.GetAllInstances<IEventHandler<UserNameChanged>>(); 

// must return Singleton CachedTeamService + other 
// IEventHandler<TeamCreated> implementations
container.GetAllInstances<IEventHandler<TeamCreated>>();  

// must return Singleton CachedUserLookupService
container.GetInstance<IUserLookupService>();

// must return Singleton CachedTeamService
container.GetInstance<ITeamService>();

// must return Singleton CachedUserLookupService + Singleton CachedTeamService
container.GetAllInstances<ICanRefreshCache>();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NOTE**: The information in this answer is outdated. Things have changed considerably in Simple Injector v4.

If I understand correctly, you have a component that implements multiple interfaces and you want each registration to map to the same instance of that component. So no matter whether you resolve an `ITeamService`, `ICanRefreshCache`, or `IEventHandler<TeamCreated>`, you want to get the same instance of `CachedTeamService`.

The general way to do this in Simple Injector is to create an `Registration` instance manually and register it for each interface as follows:

```cs
var registration = 
    Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<CachedTeamService>(container);

container.AddRegistration(typeof(ITeamService), registration);
container.AddRegistration(typeof(ICanRefreshCache), registration);
container.AddRegistration(typeof(IEventHandler<TeamCreated>), registration);
```

This is explained [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#register-multiple-interfaces-with-the-same-implementation).

Your case however is a bit more complicated, because you mix batch registration using the `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` with normal registrations. So you should either suppress the batch-registration of the `IEventHandler<TeamCreated>` that you want as singleton, or you need to [replace the registration](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#override-existing-registrations) completely.

Replacing the registration in this case however is not possible, because Simple Injector does not allow you to replace an registration that is part of a collection. So we can suppress registration of that type as follows:

```cs
Type[] typesToRegisterManually = new[]
{
    typeof(CachedTeamService)
};

container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IEventHandler<>),
    (service, impls) =>
    {
        container.RegisterAll(service, impls.Except(typesToRegisterManually));
    },
    assemblies);

var registration = 
    Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<CachedTeamService>(container);

container.AddRegistration(typeof(ITeamService), registration);
container.AddRegistration(typeof(ICanRefreshCache), registration);

// Using SimpleInjector.Advanced
container.AppendToCollection(typeof(IEventHandler<TeamCreated>), registration);
```

My experience however is that complex registrations are often an indication of SOLID principle violations in your code. It's hard to give any specific feedback on your design, but I find it very likely that the classes with those multiple interfaces have multiple responsibilities and will have multiple reasons to change (they violate [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)), causing you to change them while adding new features (which is a [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) violation).

Instead, there are a few things that I can advice:

- Move the logic for the generic `IEventHandler<T>` into its own class. An event handler is clearly a different responsibility and the interface name is already telling you that. This class could then depend upon the old class the logic was extracted from, or extract the logic that the event handler depends upon into its own class and let the 'old' class and the event handler both depend on this new shared class.
- The `IUserLookupService` interface isself seems like a repository in disguise, and this basically means that you are violating SRP, OCP and [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) (as explained in [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92)). So as [that article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) describes, custom queries deserve their own abstraction: `IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>`. This makes it very easy to apply cross-cutting concerns on them, makes them SOLID, and makes it really straightforward to register them using `container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric`.

What this leaves you is classes that in most cases just implement one abstraction, except the case that a class implements `ICanRefreshCache`. For this special case I suggest making a [composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) `ICanRefreshCache` implementation that allows triggering all `ICanRefreshCache` in the application. But instead of injecting an `IEnumerable<ICanRefreshCache>` into that composite, make that composite part of your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) and let it depend on the container. This allows you to search through complete configuration at runtime to find all `ICanRefreshCache` implementations.

This is what such composite might look like:

```cs
public class CanRefreshCacheComposite : ICanRefreshCache
{
    private readonly Lazy<InstanceProducer[]> canRefreshProducers;

    public CanRefreshCacheComposite(Container container) {
        this.canRefreshProducers = 
            new Lazy<InstanceProducer[]>(() => GetProducers(container).ToArray());
    }

    public void Refresh() {
        foreach (var producer in this.canRefreshProducers.Value) {
            var refresher = (ICanRefreshCache)producer.GetInstance();
            refresher.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<InstanceProducer> GetProducers(Container container) {
        return
            from producer in container.GetCurrentRegistrations()
            where typeof(ICanRefreshCache).IsAssignableFrom(
                producer.Registration.ImplementationType)
            select producer;
    }
}
```

And you can register it as follows:

```
container.RegisterSingle<ICanRefreshCache, CanRefreshCacheComposite>();

// To make sure all all ICanRefreshCache implementations that are part of
// a collection are known to the container, call Verify() when you're done
// registering.
container.Verify();
```

This way you can simply depend upon `ICanRefreshCache` from within your code, call the `Refresh` method on it, and the composite will do the rest.

Comment: does "producer.GetInstance()"  method return new instance or created instance to depending its registration type?

Comment: @oguzh4n: `InstanceProducer.GetInstance()` returns you an instance based on its lifestyle and it might be intercepted. In other words, it will apply any decorators (if applicable) and if the instance is singleton, it will always return that single instance.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem using below registration but I think there is an alternative way.

```
List<Registration> cacheableComponents = new List<Registration>();
foreach (var reg in serviceRegistrations)
{
     Lifestyle lifeStyle;
     if (lifeStyles.TryGetValue(reg.Implementation, out lifeStyle) == false)
     {
             lifeStyle = Lifestyle.Singleton;
     }

     Registration registration = null;
     if (lifeStyle == Lifestyle.Singleton)
     {
         registration = Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration(reg.Implementation, container);
     }
     else
     {
         registration = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration(reg.Implementation, container);
     }

     foreach (var service in reg.Services)
     {
       if (typeof(ICanRefreshCache) == service)
         {
             cacheableComponents.Add(registration);
             continue;
         }

          container.AddRegistration(service,registration);
     }
}
container.RegisterAll(typeof(ICanRefreshCache), cacheableComponents);
```

Comment: but when I call "container.GetAllInstances<IEventHandler<UserNameChanged>>()"  return instance is different. hımm :(