# Register all implemented interfaces by a type with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I am working to transition a project from MEF to Simple Injector, in MEF they have a call where you can register all types derived from an interface and all the interfaces that type implements

```
conventions.TypesDerivedFrom<T>()
           .ExportInterfaces()
```

In Simple Injector I can register all the types that derive from an interface with a call to `RegisterCollection` but this doesn't register all the interfaces that type implements. Basic example of the scenario I am pursuing

```
public interface IAnimal { }
public interface IDomesticAnimal { }
public interface ICat { }
public interface IDog { }
public class Cat : IAnimal, IDomesticAnimal, ICat { }
public class Dog : IAnimal, IDomesticAnimal, IDog { }

public void TestFunctionality()
{
    var container = new Container();

    Assembly[] assemblies = new [] { typeof(IAnimal).Assembly };

    // container.RegisterCollection<IAnimal>(assemblies) --> Register only IAnimal

    container.RegisterCollectionAndRelatedInterfaces<IAnimal>(assemblies);

    container.Register<AnimalShelter>();
    container.Register<AnimalPlayground>();

    // container.Verify() --> This would fail 
}  

public class AnimalShelter
{
   public AnimalShelter(IEnumerable<IDomesticAnimal> animals) {}
   public void Feed() {} 
}

public class AnimalPlayground
{
   public AnimalPlayground(AnimalShelter animalShelter, ICat cat, IDog dog) {}
}
```

This throw an exception because `ICat` doesn´t have a registered type. In order to solve this I have implemented an extension method

```
public static void RegisterCollectionAndRelatedInterfaces<T>(this Container container, 
    IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies)
{
    HashSet<Type> interfacesToRegister = new HashSet<Type>();

    var typesInterfaces = from type in container.GetTypesToRegister(typeof(T), assemblies)
                               where type.GetInterfaces().Any()
                               select new { Service = type.GetInterfaces() };

    foreach (var i in typesInterfaces)
    {
        interfacesToRegister.UnionWith(i.Service);
    }

    foreach (var i in interfacesToRegister)
    {
        var typesToRegister = container.GetTypesToRegister(i, assemblies);

        if (typesToRegister.Count() == 1)
        {
            container.Register(i, typesToRegister.Single());
        }
        else if (typesToRegister.Count() != 0)
        {
            container.RegisterCollection(i, typesToRegister);
        }               
     }
}
```

This extension method has the caveat that if the type is already registered it will throw an exception if the container is not created with the `override` option. I have tried to overcome this problem with something along the lines of

```
container.GetCurrentRegistration()
```

But it seems I cannot get all the registered types

Overall I don't have a warmth feeling about the whole process and I feel I am missing something

Is there any better way of achieving this functionality?

**EDIT**

[UML description of the scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJEKS.png)

I have around 30 concrete classes in my system under this design

I want to retrieve the same concrete types every time I request `InterfaceA`, `InterfaceB` or `InterfaceC`

```
container.GetAllInstances<InterfaceA> // Should return all concreteA...Z classes

// Not all my concrete classes implement InterfaceB
container.GetAllInstances<InterfaceB> // Should return all concreteA...K classes  (the same ones as above) 

container.GetInstance<InterfaceC> // Should return only concreteA
```

This is what I am currently doing

```
container.RegisterCollection(typeof(InterfaceA),assemblies, Lifestyle.Singleton)
container.RegisterCollection(typeof(InterfaceB),assemblies, Lifestyle.Singleton)
```

And the extension method

```
public static void RegisterCollection(this Container container, Type type, IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies, Lifestyle lifestyle)
{
    var types = container.GetTypesToRegister(type, assemblies);

    // Exception when registering the same types for a second time???
    var registrations = (from t in types
                        select lifestyle.CreateRegistration(t, container)).ToArray(); 

    foreach (var r in registrations)
    {
        container.AppendToCollection(type, r);
    }
}
```

I was expecting an exception when I went to register the same types for `InterfaceB`... but nope

I have yet to figured out how to do a batch registration for every `InterfaceC`which is specific to the concrete class in a one-one relation

> `foreach (var type in types)
>   {
>       container.Register(type.GetInterfaces().Single(i => i.EndsWith(type.Name)), type);
>   }`

I dont wan't to depend in the actual name of the classes.

Comment: I can't fully grasp what you are trying to accomplish. I can't see why you want (or why that even could work) to use `Register` in case there's just one element in the collection and `RegisterCollection` when you have 0 or multiple. An abstraction is typically -either- a one-to-one mapping -or- part of a collection. It is very unlikely you wish to register such type as one-to-one (i.e. `Register`) simply because there is just one registration, even though you have determined it is part of a collection. That's why Simple Injector makes the distinction between one-to-one and one-to-many explicit

Comment: It would be good if you could update your question and replace those animal abstraction with actual names of application's abstractions, and show some usages of how those abstractions are used (i.e. where do you inject a single one and where do you inject a collection).

Comment: Tried to update code example. ```IDomesticAnimal``` have to be registered as a collection and ```ICat``` and ```IDog``` as a one to one mapping. All of this needs to happen only registering the types derived from ```IAnimal```

Comment: So you are actually building an element shelter application?

Comment: This is more like a crude example of what I want to achieve on my system (not related with animals or shelters). This question kind of relates to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515198/how-can-i-register-a-type-with-its-interfaces-as-singleton-using-simple-injector but with a few differences

Comment: I think I still not understand your use case. Like I stated in the answer you are referring to: "My experience however is that complex registrations are often an indication of SOLID principle violations in your code. It's hard to give any specific feedback on your design, but I find it very likely that the classes with those multiple interfaces have multiple responsibilities and will have multiple reasons to change (they violate SRP), causing you to change them while adding new features (which is a OCP violation)." Since you use a non-specific example, it's hard to give specfic feedback.

Comment: @Steven see edited question..

Answer (score 2):

Application abstractions either always come in groups, or the come alone. An abstraction that is expected to have possible multiple implementations should never be registered with `Register`, but always with `Collection.Register`, even if there is just one implementation at the moment.

Exception to this rule is when you hide the complexity of the collection behind a composite implementation (which is typically a good idea). This composite is an implementation of the abstraction and wraps a collection of that same abstraction. This composite can be registered with `Register`, while all other implementations are registered as collection using `Collection.Register`. The composite pattern hides the complexity of iteration, order, retry, failure, logging away from the consumers that again can depend simply on the single abstraction.

Ignoring the existence of a composite for a moment, I see no reason why the following set of registrations would not succeed in your case:

```
container.Collection.Register<IAnimal>(assemblies);
container.Collection.Register<IDomesticAnimal>(assemblies);
container.Collection.Register<ICat>(assemblies);
container.Collection.Register<IDog>(assemblies);
```

**UPDATE**

To register collections of `IAnimal` and `IDomesticAnimal` where `ICat` and `IDog` are one-to-one mappings, you can do the following:

```
var types =
    container.GetTypesToRegister<IAnimal>(assemblies)
    .Concat(container.GetTypesToRegister<IDomesticAnimal>(assemblies))
    .Distinct();

container.Collection.Register<IAnimal>(
    types.Where(typeof(IAnimal).IsAssignableFrom));
container.Collection.Register<IDomesticAnimal>(
    types.Where(typeof(IDomesticAnimal).IsAssignableFrom));

container.Register<ICat, Cat>();
container.Register<IDog, Dog>();
```

Or to batch-register your cats and dogs:

```
foreach (var type in types)
{
    container.Register(type.GetInterfaces().Single(i => i.EndsWith(type.Name)), type);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not providing a clear code example. I can register all the types as you suggested of course. But What I want to achieve is to register all the types derived from an specific  interface  along with any other interface those type implement without explicitly tell simple injector

In my case my constructors have a dependency on either ```ICat``` or ```IDog``` not ```IEnumerable``` so I cannot register a collection of those. In the current MEF version those types get registered when  I register all the types that derived from ```IAnimal```